# Why is wp_get_attachment_image not including "full" size in srcset?

Tags: images

I am trying to get an image with it's `srcset` attribute for all the image sizes using [wp_get_attachment_image()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/). But it seems like the *"full"* (original) size is not listed:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $imageid, 'medium', false, $image_attributes); ?>
```

Gives: (I excluded non relevant attributes)

```
<img src="...image-232x300.jpg"
    srcset="...image-232x300.jpg 232w,
            ...image-768x994.jpg 768w,
            ...image-791x1024.jpg 791w">
```

Is this the expected output? How should I include *full* size (...image.jpg in this case) in the `srcset` attribute?

---

I noticed that calling `<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $imageid, 'full', false, $image_attributes); ?>` doesn't include the *full* size in `srcset` but still makes use of it if it is needed, as it is the assigned to the `src`. This seems to work well with browsers that support `srcset` (I checked network calls and only the necessary image size is called). But I am concerned to assign the full size to the `src` in [browsers that don't support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset) `srcset` feature.

Comment: Do you define the content width in your theme? If this happens to images with the sizer bigger than your content width, then maybe this is where you have a problem.

Comment: @JackJohansson the result is the same if I set it, not set it or set it to a really high value.

Comment: I did have your problem a while back, and i had to go with the manual `<img src="<?php ... ?> srcset="<?php ... ?>">` at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`srcset` assumes that all the images specified in the attribute have the same aspect ratio. As it is unlikely that the original (full) image has an aspect ratio that matches the registered image sizes it should be expected that it will never be part of a `srcset` attribute.

*Update from comments*: We also have a **max width** size restriction of 1600px that can be changed via the [`max_srcset_image_width`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/max_srcset_image_width/) filter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why wouldn't the original have the same aspect ratio as the reduced ones if these are not cropped? When the full image size is lower than one of the reduced sizes it does appear in the srcset.

Comment: not sure I understand. Uploaded images have random sizes. the chance that they match any of the defined sizes is small. as for images smaller than the defined sizes... yeh might happen with the way wordpress does things but if it does, it is a bug that should be reported (IMHO the whole feature is badly designed as there is no support for retina and cropped images are mixed with non cropped, but for the usage cases it is designed for it works properly)

Comment: We also have a max width size restriction of 1600 px that can be changed via [`max_srcset_image_width`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/max_srcset_image_width/) filter.

Comment: @birgire that is exactly the reason why it is not being included. Using the top *User Contributed Note* to remove this limitation fixes it. If you include the suggestion in an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Great, but hopefully those full size images are not humongous ;-) Since I've already upvoted Marks answer, regarding the aspect ratio, let me update his answer with my comment instead. @Alvaro

Comment: @birgire no problem. You are right, I guess raising the limit is a better idea. Thanks for the help.

Comment: hmm, forgot that detail @birgire, tnx for the edit